# Galois descent for K-groups (or for étale cohomology groups)

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-k-theory, etale-cohomology, galois-cohomology

Let $F/K$ be a Galois extension of number fields with Galois group $G$. Let $\mathcal{O}_F$ and $\mathcal{O}_K$ be the associated rings of integers, and let $n\geq 1$.

> When is
>   $$
> K_{2n-1}(\mathcal{O}_F)^G \cong K_{2n-1}(\mathcal{O}_K)?
> $$

It would be good enough for me to have this on the prime-to-2 parts. So let $p$ be an odd prime. Then
$$
K_{2n-1}(\mathcal{O}_F)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}_p\cong H_{ét}^1(\mathcal{O}_F,\mathbb{Z}_p(n))
$$
by the Bloch-Kato conjecture, as proven by Rost, Suslin, Voevodsky and Weibel. So my question becomes:

> when is
>   $$
> H_{ét}^1(\mathcal{O}_F,\mathbb{Z}_p(n))^G \cong H_{ét}^1(\mathcal{O}_K,\mathbb{Z}_p(n))?
> $$

A concise reference to a place that summarises everything we know about this would be great! Or maybe it is clear to the experts that this is always true? That would be even better.

Comment: Your form of the Bloch-Kato conjecture surprises me.:) As for the basic question, I'm affraid that you just have a spectral sequence that converges to you left hand size, and that you have other non-zero terms in it (besides your right hand side).

Comment: @Misha I am not offering an alternative version of the Bloch-Kato conjecture. But it is known that the Bloch-Kato conjecture implies the Quillen-Lichtenbaum conjecture, which is the isomorphism between K-theory and étale cohomlogy that I quoted. I just said "by Bloch-Kato" because that's what Rost,Voevodsky, et aliae have proven.

Comment: The Quillen-Lichtenbaum conjecture:
1. Describes motivic cohomology, that is certainly related with K-theory, but only via certain spectral sequences.
2. Ignores the infinitely divisible part of K-groups.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "ignores the infinitely divisible parts of K-groups". The K-groups in question are finitely generated abelian groups with known ranks and known torsion. There is no infinitely divisible part.

Comment: Sorry; I didn't pay enough attention to your restrictions. Still, I would bet that you only have a comparison map and not an isomorphism.

Comment: The following question might be relevant : http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11209/is-there-a-simple-relationship-between-k-theory-and-galois-theory (see in particular John Rognes' answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question, but according to [these notes](http://www.ictp.it/~pub_off/lectures/lns015/Kolster/Kolster_Final.pdf) by Manfred Kolster, Proposition 2.9, the étale cohomology groups in fact always satisfy Galois descent. Should have googled harder before asking.

Comment: However, you should note that $O_K \to O_F$ is only $G$-Galois if $K \to F$ is unramified.  Galois descent for etale cohomology refers to Galois extensions of rings, not of their fraction fields.

If you are not willing to invert the ramified primes in $O_K$, you may have to work harder.  You can compare the etale cohomology localization sequence for $O_K \to K$ (with third term involving the finite residue fields) with the one for $O_F \to F$.